# Key binding for SWT Text

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp

I have a dialog(org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog) containing a Text(org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text) field. I want to add key binding.

For example: Once dialog is open when user press key 'Ctrl + E' some changes need to be performed in Text field.
How to achieve this using key binding ?

Comment: Is this an e4 or 3.x compatibility mode RCP?

Comment: Its eclipse 3.x

Comment: For a dialog you could just use a key listener on the control. You could also use the IContextService, IHandlerService and IBindingService to use a proper key definition but this is tricky in a dialog.